# GIMP crashes immediately after starting

Tags: software-installation, crash, gimp

Upon launching GIMP, the program loads completely and displays the main window and side windows. Immediately after, the program crashes with no error message. No "Sorry, the program GIMP has closed unexpectedly", "Sorry, Ubuntu has experienced an internal error." or any other such message appears. When run from the terminal, GIMP outputs the following:

```
arcane@machine:~$ gimp

(gimp:7155): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: g_object_set_valist: object class 'GeglConfig' has no property named 'cache-size'

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1553000 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:dissolve-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x15534D0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:behind-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1553C80 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:multiply-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1553F60 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:screen-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1554350 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:overlay-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1554780 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:difference-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1554B40 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:addition-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1554F80 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:subtract-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1555340 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:darken-only-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1555790 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:lighten-only-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1555BA0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:hue-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1555ED0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:saturation-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1556330 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:color-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1557000 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:value-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1557330 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:divide-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x15577B0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:dodge-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1557B20 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:burn-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1557F70 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:hardlight-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1558310 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:softlight-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1558710 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:grain-extract-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1558B70 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:grain-merge-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1558F20 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:color-erase-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1559310 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:erase-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1559730 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:replace-mode"

(gimp:7155): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1559B00 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:anti-erase-mode"

(gimp:7155): Gimp-Widgets-CRITICAL **: gimp_device_info_set_device: assertion '(info->device == NULL && GDK_IS_DEVICE (device)) || (GDK_IS_DEVICE (info->device) && device == NULL)' failed
gimp: ../../../../src/cairo-scaled-font.c:459: _cairo_scaled_glyph_page_destroy: Assertion `!scaled_font->cache_frozen' failed.
gimp: terminated: Aborted

(script-fu:7162): LibGimpBase-WARNING **: script-fu: gimp_wire_read(): error
arcane@machine:~$
```

I have tried reinstalling GIMP and Python, and switching my GNOME 3 shell theme from Numix to Radiance, which did not help. I have also tried `rm -r .gimp-2.8`, which did not help.

How can I make GIMP start?

EDIT: I installed GIMP with `sudo apt-get install gimp`, and tried reinstall with both `sudo apt-get remove gimp & sudo apt-get install gimp` and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gimp`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a known issue with the Xenial gimp and gegl-0.3 that produces these errors and *perhaps* some of the instability you are seeing:

- [Bug 770848 - Gimp 2.8.X with gegl-0.3 compiles, but causes lots of startup warnings](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=770848)
- [Launchpad - Lots of GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING on starting gimp](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gimp/+bug/1576977)

You will have to live with this I suspect as the alternatives of recompiling against a lesser version `gegl` look a little cumbersome.

If your machine is not used for production work and you want to live on the potentailly bleeding edge there is a PPA for the development version of gimp that does *not* show this error.

***Warning: this version of gimp will not always work and should not be used on a production machine!!!***

Add the PPA and the newer gimp as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gimp
```

The version of gimp installed in this manner did not have the crazy Terminal errors and has been quite stable *so far* on my system:

[image: Click for full sized image...]
*Click for full sized image...*

Two further notes:

1. If you find that this particular iteration on the development cycle is quite stable (and this has been my experience so far) perhaps *pin* this version and avoid further updates:

   ```
   sudo apt-mark hold gimp
   ```
2. If you go this path spend a little time, as I have done, to sort out the initial dark background and icon themes. The opening themes do not sell gimp at all well :).

Comment: Note that most of these are warnings, and the actual error is near the end: