# Ubuntu 16.04 Gimp & UFRaw crash when Loading Canon CR2 Files

Tags: crash, canon, gimp

I’ve recently loaded Gimp and the Ufraw plugin into 16.04 so I can process canon CR2 raw files. Trying to open CR2 files via Gimp/File/Open, or if I select the same file via UFRaw I get the error: 
 *“Opening 'file location & name' failed: Procedure 'file-ufraw-load' returned no return values”*.

Gimp loading and working with JPEGS works OK.

Note if I start Gimp via the terminal there is a page of warnings same as in [831794](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831794/gimp-crashes-immediately-after-starting); eg

*(gimp:5187): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING : Cannot change name of operation class 0x14F74B0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:dissolve-mode"*  etc

Running UFRaw from the terminal also generates the 1st error above  as well as Segmentation fault (core dumped) in the terminal.
If I run '**strace ufraw'** it results in the following when UFRaw crashed:
which gave the following when it crashed:

*open("/home/daniel/.local/share/lensfun", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x4} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)*

I haven't been able to find anything like this searching the web. Can anyone shed light on this issue?
If anyone can help me to get UFRaw running properly I would appreciate it.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue.

There is a Confirmed bug report on launchpad [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gimp/+bug/1576977)

There is also an upstream bug report on bugzilla for Gnome [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=770848)

The general consensus is that they are going to move to gegl 0.3

This has not been implemented yet.  The last update was 2016-09-10 22:20:37 UTC

Comment: It would be nice if Debian & Ubuntu could finish their unilateral dependency change and also perform the required changes to GIMP itself, though :)

Comment: Thanks for the info. At least I now know it's not something I've messed up on my PC. :)