# Cannot launch gimp

Tags: 16.04, command-line, gimp, error-handling

I recently tried installing gimp from the official source with "sudo apt-get install gimp", and fixed all dependencies with "sudo apt-get -f install". But whenever I try to launch gimp (via "gimp" in terminal) it immediately closes and these error messages display:

```
(gimp:20357): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: g_object_set_valist: object class 'GeglConfig' has no property named 'cache-size'
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1701C80 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:dissolve-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1702150 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:behind-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1702910 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:multiply-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1702C60 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:screen-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1703050 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:overlay-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1703480 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:difference-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1703840 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:addition-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1703C80 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:subtract-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1704070 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:darken-only-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x17044C0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:lighten-only-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1704900 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:hue-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1704C60 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:saturation-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x17050C0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:color-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1705C80 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:value-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1706070 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:divide-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x17064F0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:dodge-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x17068E0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:burn-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1706D10 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:hardlight-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x17070D0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:softlight-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1707510 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:grain-extract-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x17078D0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:grain-merge-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1707D20 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:color-erase-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x17080C0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:erase-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1708520 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:replace-mode"
(gimp:20357): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x17088C0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:anti-erase-mode"
(gimp:20357): Gimp-Widgets-CRITICAL **: gimp_device_info_set_device: assertion '(info->device == NULL && GDK_IS_DEVICE (device)) || (GDK_IS_DEVICE (info->device) && device == NULL)' failed
(gimp:20357): Gimp-Widgets-CRITICAL **: gimp_device_info_set_device: assertion '(info->device == NULL && GDK_IS_DEVICE (device)) || (GDK_IS_DEVICE (info->device) && device == NULL)' failed
gimp: ../../../../src/cairo-scaled-font.c:459: _cairo_scaled_glyph_page_destroy: Assertion `!scaled_font->cache_frozen' failed.
gimp: terminated: Aborted
(script-fu:20369): LibGimpBase-WARNING **: script-fu: gimp_wire_read(): error
```

Does anybody have an idea how I could fix this?

Edit, output of apt-cache policy gimp:

```
apt-cache policy gimp gimp-data
gimp:
Installed: 2.8.16-1ubuntu1.1
Candidate: 2.8.16-1ubuntu1.1
Version table:
*** 2.8.16-1ubuntu1.1 500
    500 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
    500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 2.8.16-1ubuntu1 500
    500 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
gimp-data:
Installed: 2.8.16-1ubuntu1.1
Candidate: 2.8.16-1ubuntu1.1
Version table:
*** 2.8.16-1ubuntu1.1 500
    500 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
    500 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
    500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
    500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 2.8.16-1ubuntu1 500
    500 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
    500 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
```

Edit2, third party programs:

```
egrep -v '^#|^ *$|deb-src' /etc/apt/sources.list 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/diodon-team-ubuntu-stable-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/diodon-team/stable/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gyazo_gyazo-for-linux.list:deb https://packagecloud.io/gyazo/gyazo-for-linux/ubuntu/ xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jtaylor-ubuntu-keepass-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jtaylor/keepass/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mank319-ubuntu-go-for-it-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mank319/go-for-it/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/plushuang-tw-ubuntu-uget-stable-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/plushuang-tw/uget-stable/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescape.list:deb https://content.runescape.com/downloads/ubuntu trusty non-free
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list:deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/troxor-ubuntu-autokey-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/troxor/autokey/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu xenial main
```

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `apt-cache policy gimp gimp-data`. On my system gegl warnings exist, but then it starts. In your output *Gimp-Widgets-CRITICAL* look bad.

Comment: I've updated it.

Comment: I have exactly same version (*2.8.16-1ubuntu1.1*). And it works. Could you please try rename GIMPs config directory by `mv ~/.gimp-2.8 ~/.gimp-2.8-old` and then start `gimp` again.

Comment: Tried doing that, I still get the same error messages.

Comment: Do you have PPAs or thirdparty repositories in your system (add output of `egrep -v '^#|^ *$|deb-src' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` to the question)?

Comment: Added the thirdparty repositories.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/831794/gimp-crashes-immediately-after-starting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it may sound a bit weird, but are you using a third-party GTK theme? If so, try changing the theme to a default theme (like Ambiance) and see if that fixes it.

I would have posted this as a comment but apparently I don't have enough karma to do that.

Comment: I wasn't using a third party theme, but I tried changing it from Ambiance to High Contrast and suddenly gimp worked. Thanks, what a weird bug.